# What is the process to upload custom drupal themes to Drupal.org? What is relevance of "PayWithPaytm"?

Tags: community-official-site

I am new to this community, so apologies in advance for some ignorance.

I know there are forums, chat channels, ect, so I also apologize if this is the wrong medium for such questions.

**Basically, I want join the community by building my own Drupal Theme and eventually upload it to Drupal.org for other users to download and use if they wish.**

I went to my dashboard on Drupal.org where there are tabs for "Your Projects" and "Your Commits" and such, but commits is just a blank page, and projects is empty but with a message "*To learn about projects, see Contributing code on Drupal.org.*".

Clicking this hyperlink goes to this page: https://www.drupal.org/contribute-projects .

So my confusion starts here. **What does this e-commerce payment gateway plugin have to do with contributing code?** I downloaded it, the readme mentions nothing. Under the download option, there begins the info I need (like how to create a sandbox project and eventually

**So what does that PayWithPaytm plugin have to do with anything?** Do users need to pay Drupal to create a project or something? Why does the "learn about contributing" link go to an e-commerce plugin?

Below is a screenshot of my dashboard and the link to PayWithPaytm.

[image: Here you can see My Projects page, and in the bottom left, the link that goes to the PayWithPaytm plugin]

Comment: It looks like you reached the project page by mistake; it has nothing to do contributing projects and it is not required for contributions on drupal.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal community pages are basically a Wiki done in Drupal.  As such, anyone can get authorized to make changes.  However, like a Wiki, people can add spam like this.  This page was spammed today.

I've reverted the page back to the last revision so it should now be helpful.

Welcome to Drupal.